# For XML Path: How to keep Attribute and Value in the same node

Tags: sql, xml, for-xml-path

I have some problem when using `FOR XML PATH`. My situation is:

I have run the script as below, the attribute `CCY` and value of `AMOUNT` is merged to the same node:

> Script 1:

```
SELECT 'USD' AS 'Amount/@Ccy',
       123000 AS Amount,
       'Foo' AS Foo
FOR XML PATH('root'), TYPE;
```

Result 1: Only 1 `AMOUNT` node in `root` node

```
<root>
  <Amount Ccy="USD">123000</Amount>
  <Foo>Foo</Foo>
</root>
```

> Script 2: I change the order of `Foo` to the middle, and the result is
>   wrong

```
SELECT 'USD' AS 'Amount/@Ccy',
       'Foo' AS Foo,
       123000 AS Amount
FOR XML PATH('root'), TYPE;
```

Result 2: There are 2 nodes `AMOUNT` in the root node

```
<root>
  <Amount Ccy="USD" />
  <Foo>Foo</Foo>
  <Amount>123000</Amount>
</root>
```

So my question is: How to keep them in the same node without putting them together. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is at it is meant to work...

The engine is travelling down the column list, opens an element, fills in nested elements, finds a new element (Oh! I have to close the last one!)... and so on.

An attribute **must** be stated **before the containing element**. The order matters!

Try it out:

--identical name: You might be surprised

```
SELECT 1 AS [SomeElement]
      ,2 AS [SomeElement]
FOR XML PATH('SomeTag'),ROOT('root');
```

--A different name in between

```
SELECT 1 AS [SomeElement]
      ,'in between' AS [SomeOther]
      ,2 AS [SomeElement]
FOR XML PATH('SomeTag'),ROOT('root');
```

--The different element is - well - not there (you can use NULL as well)

```
SELECT 1 AS [SomeElement]
      ,''
      ,2 AS [SomeElement]
FOR XML PATH('SomeTag'),ROOT('root');
```

--What do you think what will come out here?

```
SELECT 'blah' AS [SomeElement/@TheAttribute]
      ,1 AS [SomeElement]
      ,2 AS [SomeElement]
FOR XML PATH('SomeTag'),ROOT('root');
```

--...and here?

```
SELECT 'blah' AS [SomeElement/@TheAttribute]
      ,1 AS [SomeElement]
      ,''
      ,'blub' AS [SomeElement/@TheAttribute]
      ,2 AS [SomeElement]
FOR XML PATH('SomeTag'),ROOT('root');
```

--This is - finally - your example (in principles)

```
SELECT 1 AS [SomeElement]
      ,'in between' AS [SomeOther]
      ,'blub' AS [SomeElement/@TheAttribute]
FOR XML PATH('SomeTag'),ROOT('root');
```

--And - just for fun! - try this too

```
SELECT 1 AS [SomeElement]
      ,NULL
      ,'blub' AS [SomeElement/@TheAttribute]
FOR XML PATH('SomeTag'),ROOT('root');
```

Comment: Thank sir. The order matters :)

Answer (score 1):

Use following, Select sequence does matter.

```
SELECT 'USD' AS 'Amount/@Ccy',123000 AS Amount,
   'Foo' AS Foo FOR XML PATH('root'), TYPE;
```

Refer working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7540/5220)