# SQL - FOR XML - Placing nearly same elements next to each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml

I have the a stored procedure to generate an `XML` document based on the `UBL-TR-2.1` standard.
I just learned how to add attributes (i.e. `schemeID="VKN"`) to an element inside my query.
Now I have a different issue:

The `UBL-TR-2.1` standard defines to put 3 times `cac:PartyIdentification` with `cbc:ID`, but different `schemeID` attributes as you can see here:

```
...
<cac:PartyIdentification>
   <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN">1190538652</cbc:ID>
</cac:PartyIdentification>
<cac:PartyIdentification>
   <cbc:ID schemeID="TICARETSICILNO">622171</cbc:ID>
</cac:PartyIdentification>
<cac:PartyIdentification>
   <cbc:ID schemeID="MERSISNO">0119053865200011</cbc:ID>
</cac:PartyIdentification>
...
```

So I tried this in my `sql` query (I post only the relevant parts of the query):

```
SELECT
    @XMLData = xmldat.xmldataCol 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (

        SELECT
            ....
            'VKN'               as 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID/@schemeID',
            v2.TAXNRM           as 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID',
            'TICARETSICILNO'    as 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID/@schemeID',
            '622171'            as 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID',
            'MERSISNO'          as 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID/@schemeID',
            '0119053865200011'  as 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID',
            ...
        FROM 
            vorgang2 (nolock) v2
        FOR XML PATH('') , ROOT('Invoice') 
    ) as xmldataCol
) as xmldat
```

But this throws an error (here orignal message in german):

> Msg 6852, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_RTIR_TR_Export_to_XML, Line
>   85 [Batch Start Line 7] Die attributzentrierte
>   cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID/@schemeID-Spalte
>   darf in der XML-Hierarchie in FOR XML PATH nicht auf ein nicht
>   attributzentriertes gleichgeordnetes Element folgen.

In english it is something like this:

> Msg 6852, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_RTIR_TR_Export_to_XML, Line
>   85 [Batch Start Line 7] The attribute-trusted
>   cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID/@schemeID
>   column in the XML hierarchy in FOR XML PATH must not follow a
>   non-attribute-trusted parental element.

So the issue seems to be, that the elements are nearly the same. And here got `sql` trouble with placing them next to each other. 
Is there any solution to this problem?
Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

The solution with adding `null` in between, does not work properly, because I get this results in the `xml`:

```
<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
   <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
         <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN"/>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
   </cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
   <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
         <cbc:ID schemeID="TICARETSICILNO">622171</cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
   </cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
   <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
         <cbc:ID schemeID="MERSISNO">0119053865200011</cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
   </cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
```

The elements `<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>` and `<cac:Party>` should not be repeated. The structure should be like this:

```
<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
   <cac:Party>
      ...
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
         <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN">1190538652</cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
         <cbc:ID schemeID="TICARETSICILNO">622171</cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
         <cbc:ID schemeID="MERSISNO">0119053865200011</cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      ...
   </cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to separate it with empty column name. to determine its unbounded rows.

```
        SELECT      
            (SELECT            
                'VKN'               as 'cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID/@schemeID',
                 v3.TAXNRM        as 'cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID',
                null,
                'TICARETSICILNO'    as 'cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID/@schemeID',
                '622171'            as 'cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID',
                null,
                'MERSISNO'          as 'cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID/@schemeID',
                '0119053865200011'  as 'cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID'

             FROM 
             vorgang2(nolock) v3 
             WHERE v3.pk = v2.pk FOR XML path('cac:Party')
                    ,root('cac:AccountingSupplierParty')
                    ,type)

        FROM 
            vorgang2(nolock) v2

        FOR XML PATH('') , ROOT('Invoice')
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, actually I'm afraid it's not exactly the answer. Please check the original post in the update section. But many thanks anyway!

Comment: we need to rebuild your nested xml via subquery, replace  WHERE v3.pk = v2.pk to correlate your subquery on your main table.

Comment: Thanks. I also needed to replace the namespaces in `<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>`, but that is no issue.

Comment: @dns_nx Just to add on this: [You might read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50321061/5089204) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805090/5089204) for some explanation. +1 from my side...